# How do Install software to a remote computer using chocolatey?

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I have installed chocolatey on my local machine and I want to, to install software remotely using powershell, I would greatley appreciate it If I can receive any help.

Comment: I am using powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`invoke-command -ComputerName $remotemachine -Credential (Get-Credential) -ScriptBlock {install choco same way as local}`

`invoke-command -ComputerName $remotemachine -Credential (Get-Credential) -ScriptBlock {choco install package xyz}`

or start a session to the remote client via `New-PSSession`?